# Reload DIV content with onchange javascript

Tags: javascript

my problem is:
I change the source of a  element which is nested in a  depending on the choosen option in a  element.

```
<select id="opWhere" onchange="changeFunc();">
        <option value="0">please select</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        ...
</select>
<div id="apiContainer">
    <div id='123'> -content by api- </div>
    <script id="apiTag" type='text/javascript' src=''></script>
</div>
<script>
   function changeFunc(){
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("opWhere");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

        var apiTag = document.getElementById("apiTag");
        
        var source = "...&uid=" + selectedValue + "...";
        
        apiTag.setAttribute("src", source);
    }
<script>
```

But nothing is changing because i also need to refresh the div-content.

Comment: This is not a good approach. Switching libraries like this is wasteful. Just reference all the scripts and then call what you need to or combine all the scripts into a single file and call what you need to.

Comment: When I pasted your code I got `changeFunc is not defined` error. The javascript code should be before `<select>`.